# ANSI C MultiPlatform Compiler and GUI

Tags: c

Hi guys I have an ANSI C university course.
I am looking for a compiler that will easily create 
makefiles and .o files and binaries that would work on both windows and ubuntu.
all code i write must be multiplatform.

(Im a C#/C++ programmer, didn't touch C for over 10 years)

no need for any external library support except ones that are part of the spec.

I assume its C99 though might be C90

nice Dev Env GUI preferably same for both windows and ubuntu is needed as well

how to make sure I don't use none-standard libraries?

Comment: ANSI C is the common name for C89.

Comment: "how to make sure I don't use none-standard libraries?" Well, refrain from doing so. Don't link to anything other than the C runtime.

Comment: I doubt there is a compiler that creates makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think gcc is your best option. On Windows the best port is probably [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

---

You edited your question to request an IDE too. Try [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

Comment: Note that [MinGW-w64](mingw-w64.sourceforge.net) is better at C99 math support and a lot of other things.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend Eclipse as the IDE. It has some issues on Windows, but it is great on Linux.

GCC/MinGW as compiler doesn't need much discussing.